# How to know the last view index of MultiView on ActiveViewChanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to know what was the last view index on the event `ActiveViewChanged`?

```
protected void mltv_ActiveViewChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Here i nedd to know what it was, because here it is already changed  
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Show your work..

Answer (score 0):

Check the property `mltv.ActiveViewIndex`.  Got [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.activeviewindex.aspx).

Comment: I just happened to come across this post by accident, years later, but it is wrong.  When you reference ActiveViewIndex in the ActiveViewChanged event you'll get the current index and not the index before.  I'll post a quick snippet of how to access the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just used the Load Event for user control and reference the ActiveViewIndex.  It should have the ActiveViewIndex before it has been changed.  For the example below I just used the context items as backing, but if you have a class level variable that could be used instead:

```
protected void mltv_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Add your property backing or class variable here
   int pos = mltv.ActiveViewIndex;
   if (pos == -1)
       return;
   Context.Items["mltv_ActiveViewIndexOnLoad"] = pos;

}
protected void mltv_ActiveViewChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Retrieve property, private variable, here:
   var lastViewIndex = -1; 
   if (Context.Items["mltv_ActiveViewIndexOnLoad"] != null)
   {
       lastViewIndex = (int)(Context.Items["mltv_ActiveViewIndexOnLoad"]);
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes I know this is a late post, but Freddie Fabregas' answer is wrong.  It will provide the ActiveViewIndex after it has been changed.  The load event will give you the index before it has been changed.